# scaling an image for a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add image to cell, it works, but the scaling is not really working, the image is scaled to some size, and stay in that size, numbers i enter to the scale function don't change a thing .(image is auto scale to some constant size)

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:icon];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *logo=[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:4];
        cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
        cell.imageView.image=logo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this method and use it:

```
/*! Returns a UIImage which is resized image of the image provided.
    @param image
        The image to be resized.
    @param size
        The size of the image to be resized.
*/
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image imageSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat requiredWidth = (imageWidth * size.height) / imageHeight;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(requiredWidth, size.height), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, requiredWidth, size.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    //here is the scaled image which has been changed to the size specified
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your masking function inside the custom cell class method declared as below.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    [self.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
    self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to scale the images as per your requirement.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    float theScaleFactor = 0.0f;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0) {
            theScaleFactor = 2.0f;
        } else {
            theScaleFactor = 0.0f;
        }
    } else {
        theScaleFactor = 0.0f;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, theScaleFactor);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

**Hope this will help you.**